# Removing class in WordPress plugins file - not working without page refresh for the first time

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have a class called `event-manager` in a wordpress php file in the plugins folder. They are using this class to style the elements, and I am using a custom css to over-write this. The problem is I cannot overwrite their css so I had to remove this class all-together.

I need to remove this class dynamically, removing manually every-time is pointless, because every-time the plugin gets updated the class comes back.

And here the html structure. The class appears on two different pages and on both pages the image alignment is different.

```
<!-- Home page -->
<div class="some-class">
    <div class="some-more-class">
        <div class="featured-image"> <!-- this image alignment is different -->
            <div class="event-image"> <!-- this div is generated dynamically from the plugin -->
                <a href="#"> some link </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Blog single -->
<div class="some-class">
    <div class="some-more-class">
        <div class="featured-img"> <!-- and image alignment is different -->
            <div class="event-image"> <!-- this div is generated dynamically from the plugin -->
                <a href="#"> some link </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

To acheive this I used jquery `.removeClass` method.

```
$(function(){
    $(".featured-img > div, .featured-image > div").removeClass("event-manager");
    });
```

I also tried this

```
$(function(){
    $(".featured-img > div").removeClass("event-image");
    $(".featured-image > div").removeClass("event-image");
    });
```

And this

```
var featuredimg = ['.featured-img > div','.featured-image > div'];
$(featuredimg.join()).removeClass('event-image');
```

On all these methods, the class seems to be removed, because its on two different pages, when I load the `homepage.php` for the first time, the class is removed but when I go to `single.php`, it did not remove automatically and when I refresh the page, the class removes. I am not sure why.

Can anyone help me.
Thanks.

Comment: maybe you have a one page site ? going to the single.php doesn't load the page so the jquery doen't execute until you reload the page again.

Comment: by the way am sure you can overrid their CSS, can you show us the CSS of this class ?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinions it is related with caching. Do you have any? If yes disable it to test if works without it. If no you can check on developer console if do you have any errors. Issue can be also with place the script like this (prefer at the end of the page).